# How can I prevent air leaks in my single-hung windows?

Tags: insulation, windows, leak, air-leaks

In our house we have regular single-hung windows which are leaking cold air.

As usual, the double pane unit is encased in plastic trim. I can feel a draft coming out where the plastic has a seam with the glass. There is a bead of rubber going all along the seam, and it doesn't looked peeled off.

1. Is this a common problem? Could I be imagining a leak in this spot?
2. How do I fix it? Is applying a bead of silicone over the rubber seal a bad idea?

The arrows point to where the seam is:

[image]

Comment: For future reference, a "regular, double pane, slide up-down windows" is called a "double hung window". Some are single pane, most double pane and some are even triple pane. Now you can sound like a pro! Yes, pics are always good.

Comment: Storm windows  are an option

Comment: Vertically sliding windows come in single hung and double hung. In single hung the lower section moves up and down but the upper section is fixed. In double hung the top section moves down and up. The hung part must come from the fact that heavy old wooden windows were held by cables or chains going up over pulleys and then down inside pockets  on the sides to hanging weights, one on each side. Each weight would be half the total weight of that moveable section. Light modern windows are supported by friction, but they arecstill said to be "hung". Most modern windows are single hung.

Comment: double-paned windows are supposed to have the airspace in between completely sealed.   The best ones often put 100% nitrogen in there.  If you are feeling air coming from the seal between the glass and the plastic frame then either your feeler is wrong and the air is coming from somewhere else or the window seal is shot.  If the window seal is shot any attempt to reseal it will trap mold spores and dust in there causing lots of nasty stuff to grow in between the panes of glass if you were to be able to seal it.

Comment: Double-paned windows are made as a single self-contained unit, factory sealed, which is then just clipped into the frame. The frame can be leaky without the sealed unit being damaged. If that's all it is, then yes, you can silicone round the edges, or see Ed's answer below for a more permanent fix - new seals.

Comment: just for sake of completeness, in the UK any pair of panes (no matter how many layers thick) which slide over each other vertically is known as a **sash** window, because back in the day they relied on counter-balancing weights hanging on a substantial ropes (sash rope) inside the frame sides to make movement smoother. This was how you could open a well-maintained sash window no matter how large with just one hand.

Comment: @JimStewart _very_ valid point about the single- vs double-hung distinction. However, I don't think "most modern windows are single hung". We just replaced ours 2 summers ago and _none_ of the salesmen mentioned a single thing about a single hung (not even as an option). They all touted the tilt out feature on _both_ sashes (slide the top one down to access it) for ease of cleaning. _Of course, we're wandering off topic now..._

Comment: It may be worth looking for a manufacturer label. Many windows have 20+ year warranties that may even be transferable to a new home owner. If you contact the mfgr, they can give you an idea of what kind of warranty coverage you may have. Ours (replaced 2 summers ago) have a lifetime transferable warranty, so this kind of issue would result in them building a whole new sash to replace the failing one.

Answer (score 2):

On the windows I have installed they have a clear plastic or white wiper that seals to the frame, when these windows get older that plastic seal fails then the outside air can make it through the gap. You may need to remove the slider and look on some windows I have seen several of these, wiper type weather seals. The seals pull out to a side if they don’t slide out with players look for a staple keeping them from moving.

You may be able to find a generic weather strip that will replace yours. It’s not horribly difficult pulling the window can be the hardest part.

The entire sliding part it probably will need to come out so you can remove and replace.

Comment: Often the plastic retainers just clip in/out - tougher to get out because there's no real way to get into them. A screwdriver blade will do it if you start at the corner with the most significant gap (they're almost never perfect on all 4 sides.) just lever directly towards you from one end, then you can pull the first one away. After that it's plain sailing. Ream out the old seals, replace with new & snap the retainers back in. I doubt it would be difficult to do in-situ, no matter whether it's a sash, or even tilt & turn. The retainers will be nowhere near any mechanism.